# React-Leaflet: Marker has wrong position after zoom out

Tags: leaflet, markers, zoom, react

When I show a marker in the center of the map it is OK.
But when I zoom out, the marker is like staying at the same place. Finally its position is very wrong.

Why is it not moving together with the map when zooming out?

I user react-leaflet:

```
const customMarker = new L.icon({
    iconUrl: '/images/icons/location-pointer.svg',
    iconSize: new L.Point(35, 46),
});

...

renderMarker(position) {
    if (position) {
        return (
            <Marker 
                position={[position.lat, position.lng]} 
                icon={customMarker} 
            >
            </Marker>
        );
    }
}

...

render() {
        return (
            <Map 
                ref={this.mapRef}
                center={positionMap} 
                zoom={position.zoom}
                onClick={this.handleClick}
                onMoveend={this.handleMoveEnd}
                dragging={true}
                scrollWheelZoom={false}
            >
                <TileLayer
                    attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
                    url="https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"
                />
                    { this.renderMarker(this.props.locationData.locations[0]) }

            </Map>
        );
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with the marker positioning, it just depends on the way marker icon is defined.

Since you defined marker icon without `iconAnchor` option, marker is positioned so that center of the icon is at `[position.lat, position.lng]` position. If your icon has dimensions `[35, 46]` and you want the bottom tip of the icon to be at desired position, you must define your icon as:

```
const customMarker = new L.icon({
    iconUrl: '/images/icons/location-pointer.svg',
    iconSize: [35, 46],
    iconAnchor: [17, 46]
});
```

There is one other condtion for `.svg` icon to be positioned properly. `viewBox` of `.svg` icon has to correspond to icon dimensions.